# How to debug a QGIS python plugin with popups?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I'm trying to write a `python` plugin for `QGis`. I'd like to debug some DB queries and I need a way to display the result.

I thought about using a popup to display it, but I don't know how to show a **popup** from inside a `python` plugin.

Can anyone suggest me how to do that?

Comment: related: How to setup a debugger for QGIS Plugin development? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62657/how-to-setup-a-debugger-for-qgis-plugin-development

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I solved this way:

```
def printMsg(self,msg):
    QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(),"Debug",msg)
```

I don't know if it's the best way to go, but it seems to work fine.