# How to setup a debugger for QGIS Plugin development?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, development, python-2.7, plugins

As the title of the question implies, I wish to know how to set up a QGIS Python Plugin Debugger so that I can develop plugins more efficiently.

Any information regarding this would be much appreciated as I am fairly new to QGIS Python Plugin Development.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: @iant based on his previous question, I think he is free to chose any: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62553/best-platform-to-develop-qgis-python-plugins

Comment: Apologies for the late reply @iant I am currently using Windows but if need be I will use an alternative environment.

Answer (score 1):

Plugins are written in Python, so use a Python debugger as [pdb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) present in the standard distribution

[image]

and look [Python module of the week: pdb – Interactive Debugger](http://pymotw.com/2/pdb/), [Debugging in Python](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2009/09/10/debugging-in-python/) or the multiple tutorials on the Web.

Or choose another one of those presented in [Python Debugging Tools](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggingTools)

Comment: You can't drop into `pdb` while running the plugin, though...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a step-by-step debugger, you can use the [RemoteDebug](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/remotedebug/) plugin which integrates nicely with [PyDev](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pydev-python-ide-eclipse#.Ua3YZnF1uY4) and [Eric](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/). But success has been reported with other [environments](http://linfiniti.com/2012/09/remote-debugging-qgis-plugins-using-pycharm/) as well.

[This recent StackExchange question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62303/how-to-add-qgis-python-api-intellisense-support-in-aptana-studio3-pydev) concerning code completion may be interesting as well.

Answer (score 1):

See this: http://linfiniti.com/2011/12/remote-debugging-qgis-python-plugins-with-pydev/
and this: http://linfiniti.com/2012/09/remote-debugging-qgis-plugins-using-pycharm/
for information on debugging with PyDev and PyCharm respectively.

Comment: Both those links are dead, which is why links are _not_ preferred on StackExchange sites. If you can find them again, better would be to copy/paste/redo-the-steps for reference here, and have the links as an aside

Answer (score 1):

The links posted by gsherman are available on the wayback machine for anyone (like me) trying to solve the same problem: https://web.archive.org/web/20160315041546/http://linfiniti.com/2011/12/remote-debugging-qgis-python-plugins-with-pydev/
They are blog posts with lots of pictures, so I won't copy/paste them here.

Comment: is this an actual way of working with QGIS plugins even now in 2023?

Comment: I'm trying it now, will return if I figure it out!

Comment: Seems to work perfectly! Now, if only I could say the same about my plugin...